# Nagios check_mem reports incorrect swap usage

Tags: centos6, nagios, swap, top

We use check_mem.pl to check memory usage in Nagios. On one of our CentOS 6 servers, the check reports a warning about swap usage. However, upon checking, the server doesn't seem to use any swap.

This is what top says:

[top output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JycK6.png)

And the nagios check_mem.pl output:

```
-bash-4.2$ ./check_mem.pl -w 99,25 -c 100,50 -v
<b>WARNING: Memory Usage: (W> 99, C> 100): 34% - Total: 7823 MB, used: 2697 MB, free: 5126 MB<br>Swap Usage: (W> 25, C> 50): 27% - Total: 9871 MB, used: 2697 MB, free: 7174 MB<br></b>|MemUsed=34%;99;100 SwapUsed=27%;25;50
```

Why does check_mem report 2697MB swap usage while top reports a swap usage of 0?

Comment: Sounds like a poorly written plugin... which check_mem.pl are you using? This is not a standard plugin

Comment: Some detail information: check_mem v$Revision: 1.8 $ (nagios-plugins 2.0.3) / Copyright (c) 2005 Garrett Honeycutt/Rouven Homann/Cedric Temple

Comment: I found another check_mem.pl script here: https://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Operating-Systems/Solaris/check_mem-2Epl/details which works much better :)